# Monitoring AWS by Nagios

Tags: ubuntu, aws, nagios

I have an AWS EC2 project to be monitored by Nagios.

My Nagios runs on a server outside of AWS.

Service monitoring works, but host monitoring does not.

How can I fix it?

```
define host {
       use                             linux-server
       host_name                       myserver.com
       alias
       address                         44.211.111.211
       max_check_attempts              5
       check_period                    24x7
       notification_interval           30
       notification_period             24x7
}

define service{
    host_name               myserver.com
    service_description     myserver.com_web
    check_command           check_https_with_auth!myserver.com
    max_check_attempts      5
    check_period            24x7
    notification_interval   30
    notification_period     24x7
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nagios by default uses ICMP ("Ping") to test host reachability.

Update the **EC2 Security Group** to permit ICMP access from your Nagios address - that will fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you very much . it works for me.